# "Subtracting" strings from a string in excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet ***with a single column*** containing 50 rows of comma-delimited text. The number of commas  increases at random intervals up the sheet. Each time a comma is added, a new word is added in a random position to the existing string:

```
FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE
FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE
FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE
FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE
TRUE,TRUE,FALSE
TRUE,TRUE,FALSE
TRUE,TRUE
TRUE,TRUE
TRUE,TRUE
TRUE
```

I would like to find what is being added to the string in each row, for example:

```
N/A
TRUE
N/A
FALSE
N/A
FALSE
N/A
N/A
TRUE
N/A
```

So far I have tried comparing each row (for example row 2) to the row beneath it (row 3), and removing the text in row 3 from row 2 using the search function:

```
=(ISERROR(SEARCH(Q52,Q51,1)),Q51,RIGHT(Q51,LEN(Q51)-LEN(Q52)))
```

This works if the new text is added to the beginning or the end of the string, but does not if the new text is added in the middle of the string. Does anyone know of a workaround to this?

Comment: Can you explain the input/output? Where did `2` add `TRUE`? It looks the same as `1`?  Edit: Oh, are you starting from the bottom up?  Is the new word *always* at the end of the string? Or could it be added to the middle?

Comment: Yes, it's starting from the bottom up. The new word is added randomly to the existing string i.e it could be added to the middle,beginning, end etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help too, it allows for multiple additions

```
=IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B4,"TRUE","0"))=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B4,"TRUE","0"),"0","")),0,LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B4,"TRUE","0"))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B4,"TRUE","0"),"0","")))
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XlkI.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZlOL.png

Answer (score 2):

Use,

```
=IF(A2="",NA(),IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"TRUE",""))<>LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"TRUE","")),"TRUE",IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"FALSE",""))<>LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"FALSE","")),"FALSE",NA())))
```

Which compare the number of trues and falses to the one below and returns the difference.

[image]

Comment: This is an excellent solution in the case of a TRUE/ FALSE binary. However, is there an ambiguous solution that would work for the addition of random text?

Comment: @bm13563 then your example should show that it is random text and not just True or False.

Comment: @bm13563 you will need vba and not a formula.

Comment: Understood, I will mark the question as answered since your solution works for the example posted. I will then post the same question on the vba forum with an adapted example.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very elegant solution in the case of a non TRUE/FALSE bindary i.e if the text is random rather than TRUE/FALSE.

[How can I tell the differences between two strings in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43351835/how-can-i-tell-the-differences-between-two-strings-in-excel)