# Identifying different values between two strings of text in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm importing lab info into excel, that's all text, but I need to compare before and after results, and ID which results are now negative.
For example, cell A1 = "A3 B27 A23 DQ8" and cell B1 = "A3 A23 DR16". I was hoping I could use a VBA function to return values "B27 DQ8" into cell C1 - the results that are now no longer in the string of text.
I was referencing this post [How can I tell the differences between two strings in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43351835/how-can-i-tell-the-differences-between-two-strings-in-excel)

and the code was

```
Function CompareStrings(keyRng As Range, ansRng As Range) As String <br />
Dim arr() As String <br />
Dim i As Long <br />
arr() = Split(ansRng.Value, "|") <br />
For i = 0 To UBound(arr) <br />
    If InStr(keyRng.Value, arr(i)) = 0 Then <br />
        CompareStrings = arr(i) <br />
        Exit Function <br />
    End If <br />
Next I <br />
End Function <br />

UDF: =CompareStrings(A2,B2)
```

which worked, except for it's only returning one value, instead of the multiples that are now negative.

I've also tried this highlighting code https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3716-excel-compare-two-strings-highlight-differences-for-similarity.html
But I think it's considering the whole string of text as one value, instead of being separated by spaces.

Unfortunately, the info I'm being given has dozens of values within one string of text, and they are not in any numerical or alphabetical order so it makes sorting it much more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

If one has access to `TEXTJOIN()` you could use:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",,FILTERXML(SUBSTITUTE("<x><t>"&A1&" "&"</t></x>"," ","<s> "&B1&" </s></t><t>"),"//t[.//*[not(contains(.,concat(' ',../text(),' ')))]]"))
```

The trick here is to create a valid `XML` expression:

```
<x>
    <t>A3
        <s> A3 A23 DR16 </s>
    </t>
    <t>B27
        <s> A3 A23 DR16 </s>
    </t>
    <t>A23
        <s> A3 A23 DR16 </s>
    </t>
    <t>DQ8
        <s> A3 A23 DR16 </s>
    </t>
    <t>
    </t>
</x>
```

Whereas the `XPATH` expression will return all `<t>` nodes where it's child does **not** contain the text of it's parent `<t>` node. We concatenate with spaces to make sure we are not matching bits and pieces for false positives.

And yes, if you do not have access to `TEXTJOIN` but you do have Excel 2013 (and therefor access to `FILTERXML`) you could easily create an UDF to emulate `TEXTJOIN`. For example:

```
Function TEXTJOIN(XMLstr As String, XPATHstr As String) As String
    With Application
        TEXTJOIN = Join(.Transpose(.FilterXML(XMLstr, XPATHstr)), " ")
    End With
End Function
```

Which could be called through `=TEXTJOIN(SUBSTITUTE("<x><t>"&A1&" "&"</t></x>"," ","<s> "&B1&" </s></t><t>"),"//t[.//*[not(contains(.,concat(' ',../text(),' ')))]]")`.

Answer (score 0):

To do this using VBA, I'd suggest using the Dictionary object.

- Each space separated substring from A is added to the dictionary.
- Each space separated substring from B that is in the dictionary, is removed from the dictionary.

```
Option Explicit
Function compareStrings(S1 As String, S2 As String) As String
    Dim myD As Object, v, w, I As Long
    
Set myD = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    myD.comparemode = vbTextCompare
    
v = Split(S1)

For Each w In v
    If Not myD.exists(w) Then myD.Add w, w
Next w

v = Split(S2)
For Each w In v
    If myD.exists(w) Then myD.Remove w
Next w

compareStrings = Join(myD.keys)

End Function
```

You could also do this using Power Query.
The algorithm is the same except using Lists instead of a Dictionary:

```
let
    //Change table name in next line to reflect name of table on your worksheet

    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table10"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Column3", 
        each 
            List.RemoveMatchingItems(
                    Text.Split([Column1]," "), Text.Split([Column2]," "))),

    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Column3", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), " "), type text})
in
    #"Extracted Values"
```

[image]